# Can't create App Store account?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Every time I attempt to create an App Store account, I get the following error:

[image: Apple.]

> **Your session has timed out. Please try again.**
>
> Code: 5107

This error has persisted for weeks; I'm effectively locked out of the App Store, and everything that comes from it. (Which, as a developer, means a lot of things, since tons of stuff annoyingly depends on Xcode.)

Comment: Like `brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim`; apparently that requires Xcode…

Comment: As a workaround, you can install Xcode-beta from https://developer.apple.com/download/. If that doesn't work then there must be something wrong with your Apple ID.

Comment: I don't have an Apple ID yet; I'm stuck trying to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to use for an App Store account is your Apple ID.

If what you're trying to do is create an Apple ID and you keep running into Code: 5107 errors, you can try using a browser instead to create your Apple ID.

To do this:

- Launch Safari (or your preferred web browser)
- Go to: https://appleid.apple.com/account
- Complete the form etc to create your Apple ID

Once you've created your Apple ID (or if you already had an Apple ID), sign in to the App Store. You can do this as follows:

- Launch the App Store app
- Click on the Store menu
- Select Sign In...
- Enter your Apple ID
- Enter your Password
- Click on Sign In.

If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Comment: This sounded like it could work, and it does get me an AppleID. However, if you attempt to use the ID to sign into the App Store, it says, "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store."; it then proceeds to prompt for payment information (which I do not have), and the "None" option is not displayed.

Comment: _Actually_, the None payment option appears if I try to upgrade a free app. (Just not if I just sign in normally…) Technically, I think that worked. (It said my account was now usable w/ the App Store or something) However, clicking any "Update" button just causes the button to grey out, and an AJAX spinner to appear, spin for a while, and then disappear. So, nothing works, but I think I technically have an account now, so I'm awarding you the magic Internet points.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is how you go to "Create account" page wizard ..

- open iTunes then go to Apps
- choose a free app
- choose create account
- fill your info
- then "None" will appear as a payment method, select it.
- make sure you enter right zip code for the country you selected

and that's it.

Comment: If I'm remembering right, this is the method that I was attempting to use; the error occurs after submitting the information on the payment screen (with None selected); i.e., after your last step. (I didn't realize prior to posting this question quite how many variations there were on creating an account.)

Comment: Yep .. i was creating it from app store and it wont work but when i accsesed the page from iTunes it worked for me and that's weird ...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the part about via iTunes. I tried a variation on Monomeeth's method, and that seemed to work, so I'm not able to test this anymore.